# How to get the current location on a button click in android using Xamarin MVVM?

Tags: c#, android, mobile, mvvm, xamarin

How to get the current location on a button click in android using Xamarin MVVM?

I am trying to use the GPS co-ordinates for background processing, I Need to get the current device location when ever user clicks on a button and I don't want to display this anywhere on my UI, tried couple of stuffs but nothing worked, can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get location in a number of ways. The button click aspect of this question is merely an event handler following the respective Command pattern in MVVM that you setup.

Example of Commands in MVVMLight(A popular MVVM library that has Xamarin support):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

Let's go over the ways you can get GPS coordinates:

1) Natively via `LocationManager`:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

2) In a Xamarin library that already provides this functionality(Which internally uses `LocationManager`:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Geolocator

Comment: Hi Jon tried to use the Xamarin library but I am not able to be successful, do you have any example on the same?
Tried using xamarin.Mobile.dll and other too

Comment: Tried using Xam.Plugin.Geolocator couldn't get the coordinates successfully

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the location listener and wait for sometime. then onlocation change will fired. Then only we can able to catch user's current location.

I prefer to show progress dialog and start the thread to listen location change.
Don't use any xamarin third party plugin. Use native [Location Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Integrate following Code.

```
 [Activity(Label = "Location Activity", MainLauncher = false, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
 public class GetLoationActivity : BaseActivity, Android.Locations.ILocationListener
    {
        Location userLocation;
        Button getLocationButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.getLocationButton);
        getLocationButton.LongClick += (e, d) =>
            {
                //TODO:Show Progress Dialog 
                var _LocationManager = LocationContext.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
                var LocationChangedCalled = false;
                var PublishAwayFenceThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
                    {
                        StartLocationChangeListener(this);
                    }
                    }));
                PublishAwayFenceThread.Start();
            };

    }

    public void StartLocationChangeListener(Activity activity)
    {
        try
        {
            var locationCriteria = new Criteria();
            locationCriteria.Accuracy = Accuracy.Coarse;
            locationCriteria.PowerRequirement = Power.Medium;
            string locationProvider = Helper.Instance._LocationManager.GetBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(locationProvider))
            if (activity!= null)
            {
                activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
                        var _LocationManager = LocationContext.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
                        _LocationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 1000, 1, this);
                        Console.WriteLine("****---------*****Location Listener Started****---------*****");
                    });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        try
        {
            userLocation = location;
            //TODO:Hide Loader
            StopLocationChangeListener();
            Console.WriteLine("****---------*****Location changed fired****---------*****");
            Console.WriteLine("****---------*****" + location.Latitude + "," + location.Longitude + "****---------*****");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void StopLocationChangeListener()
    {
        try
        {
            Activity _LocationContextAcitivity = (Activity)Helper.Instance.LocationContext;
            _LocationContextAcitivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    var _LocationManager = LocationContext.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
                    _LocationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
                    Console.WriteLine("****---------*****Location Listener stopped****---------*****");
                });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```